# How I can send my axios response to a variable with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

In fact, I begin with node.js. And i don't know how to pass the response to a variable. I don't want to make my code in my "response".. I try a lot of things but nothing is working.. I know is a simple question.. but it's not working

```
const axios = require('axios');
var test = null
function getLeagues () {
  axios.get('https://api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/v2/fixtures/league/525?timezone=Europe/Paris', {
   headers: {
    'X-RapidAPI-Key': '<my-api-key>'
   }
  })
  .then(response => {

    test = response.data.api.fixtures

    return response.data.api.fixtures
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
}

console.log(test)
```

Comment: **Warning!** You forgot to remove your private API key! Please keep in mind some people may abuse it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use promises and wait for the response to be ready:

```js
const axios = require('axios');

function getLeagues () {
  return axios.get('https://api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/v2/fixtures/league/525?timezone=Europe/Paris', {
   headers: {
    'X-RapidAPI-Key': 'foo-api-key'
   }
  })
  .then(response => {
    return response.data.api.fixtures
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
    return Promise.reject(error);
  });
}

getLeagues().then(response => {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Or, using async/await:

```
const consoleLeagues = async () => {
  const leagues = await getLeagues();
  console.log(leagues);
};

consoleLeagues();
```

Comment: I haved try this `
function getLeagues () {
  axios.get('https://api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/v2/fixtures/league/525?timezone=Europe/Paris', {
   headers: {
    'X-RapidAPI-Key': 'api-key'
   }
  })
  .then(response => {
    return response.data.api.fixtures
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
}

const consoleLeagues = async () => {
  const leagues = await getLeagues();
  console.log(leagues);
};

consoleLeagues();` but it's returning "undefined". Like my script is stoping before the response.. it's posible ?

Comment: No, it is not stopping, it is being executed but you are not waiting for the promise response. You are not returning the promise in your function. Add `return axios.get...`, as in the example of my answer.

Comment: Oh ok thank's it's working ! I need to learn more about that !

Comment: No problem! If you want to learn more about asynchronies in Nodejs (which is a crucial point if you really want to mastering Nodejs), I recommend you to first learn how Promises work, and only then, start using "async/await".